# Add new cronjob to run specific .php file

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

I use AOE Scheduler to manage my cronjobs in Magento.

Now I want to run a specific .php file that I created, to run every night at 03.00h.

How can I add this easily?

Comment: @MagenX Not exactly, because I need to run a .php file beside the default cron.sh that is already running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just need to run php file 
add simple cronjob

```
0 3 * * * php /path/to/file.php >dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks! But who can I add this cronjob inside AOE?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Create a new job](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/blob/master/doc/create-job.md) functionality in AOE, then include your file in the run method (better solution would be to copy your logic into the run mehtod)

```
class My_Module_Model_Job_Hello
{
    /**
     * Log 'Hello World'
     *
     * @param Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule $schedule
     */
    public function run(/* Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule $schedule */)
    {
        Mage::log('Hello World');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but I do not know what I need to fill in the fields Run model and Cron configuration path

Comment: Update your question with your config.xml

Comment: I do not have a config.xml file for this cronjob. Do I need to create one?

Comment: You need to create a simple magento module to use the method above